# Why libxml2 uses "BAD_CAST" everywhere in a C/C++ code?

Tags: c, linux, casting, libxml2

It's said that because libxml2 uses `unsigned char` as storage to make encoding/decoding between char sets convenient ---- isn't it ugly to force users to write "BAD_CAST" everywhere in the code, when reading/creating xml node names, contents, text nodes, etc.

It there a way to avoid writing such "BAD_CAST" everywhere? The design is really so bad.

Comment: It is bad design and they should be using `uint8_t` not `unsigned char`.

Comment: C++17 and `std::byte` makes the situation even worse for those who have `typedef unsigned char byte;`. You can't `using byte = std::byte` because `std::byte` has so many restrictions. For example, trying to `std::byte b = ...;` then `b |= 0x20;` or `b -= 0x10;`  fails to compile.

Comment: @JeremyP libxml2 was first released in 1999 when the C99 standard, which introduced  `uint8_t`, wasn't even published. Even today, there are platforms without full support for C99. Besides, C99 makes no guarantee that any of the `uint*_t` types are available. Also, how would `uint8_t` help? On most platforms, it's typedef'd to `unsigned char`, so you still have to cast things like string literals. One could only argue that libxml2 should have used plain `char`s for its public API, and cast to an unsigned type internally.

Comment: @nwellnhof Because uint8_t, if it exists, is guaranteed to be an eight bit unsigned integer value and it reflects much better the type of the individual octets than unsigned char - which needn't be eight bits.

Comment: For readability you can another macro definition such as `#define MY_CAST BAD_CAST`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This design decision is unfortunate, but rooted in another unfortunate choice made 40 years ago: allowing `char` to be potentially signed by default, which is inconsistent with the behavior of `getchar()`, `strcmp()`...

You can use an inline function to convert from `char *` to `unsigned char *` and vice-versa with a single hidden cast, and use these when passing arguments:

```
static inline unsigned char *c2uc(char *s) { return (unsigned char*)s; }
static inline char *uc2c(unsigned char *s) { return (char*)s; }
```

These wrappers are much safer to use than basic casts as they can only be applied to one type and convert to its `unsigned` counterpart.  Regular casts are problematic as they can be applied to any type and hide type conversion errors.  `static inline` functions are expanded by the compiler at no runtime cost.

Comment: You probably want to put `const` qualifiers on the parameter and the result.

Comment: @JeremyP: yes, you actually want a separate set of wrappers for const pointers  (with a different name for C) .

Comment: It might be informative to add a short explanation as to exactly *why* the macro cast is bad (ie., no type checking on the argument), and that using a `static inline` function fixes that. (And that using current C compilers, `static inline` functions are just as fast as macros.)